# How divide center circle of sunburst plot in d3? I'm using the standard zoomable sunburst

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am using the d3.js sunburst for this i want to slice center circle depend on the level can you help me?

Comment: can you be more specific what do you mean by divide ..the question is not clear

Comment: I need only modify center circle in this i want to add text can you help me?